# Using features from two independent branches?

Tags: git

I have two independent branches off of master, A and B. I want to create a new branch C that uses code that I have created in A as well as in B. I can't just branch off one of A or B because they won't have all the features by themselves. What is is the canonical way to approach this problem? git cherrypick the files that I need?

Comment: Branch from one and merge the other? Or branch from master and merge both? Merge both back to master and create a new branch from there? (I don't think there is a canonical way to do this, so just pick one that makes sense to you).

Comment: @crashmstr this situation is before I can merge them (e.g. while awaiting review) - if I could do that I would just merge to master and branch off of there.

Answer (score 1):

Create a branch from either and merge the other.  For example:

```
$ git checkout -b C A
$ get merge B
```

(Which is what @crashmstr suggested in his comment.)

Answer (score 0):

```
A > git checkout -b C
C > git rebase B
```

Your new branch C will have commits from A rebased to new commits from B. Hence, containing commits from both the branches that are not master.

Comment: Tonio Right, I don't want to put every git command for the sake of symplicity of the answer. "A >" means/assumed that you are currently at branch A or you are checked out at branch A. Secondly while rebasing if you run into conflict that can be really painful, if it's replayed over and over again. My solution also doesn't covers that.